# Login and sign up issue

Tags: firebase, android-studio, firebase-authentication, buttonclick

I am currently trying to build a new app (complete Novice) I have run into a strange issue on the login page.The sign up process works fine connects to firebase and returns to the login screen, then allows you to login and goes to the next activity. The problem occurs when you reload the app and use the details to re-login the login button does not work until you go into the sign up activity and come out of it then the login button works fine and allows you to sign in.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);


    Button button = findViewById(R.id.signupbtn);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openSignupActivity();
        }
    });
}

private void openSignupActivity() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, SignupActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    LoginEmail = findViewById(R.id.LoginEmail);
    LoginPassword = findViewById(R.id.LoginPassword);
    Loginprogressbar = findViewById(R.id.Loginprogressbar);
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    findViewById(R.id.Loginbtn).setOnClickListener(this);
```

**if conditions between**

```
if(task.isSuccessful()){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Login Successful",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
                startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this,MainActivity.class));

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.Loginbtn:
                Loginuser();
            break;`enter code here`
```

Comment: What code would i write i have tried a few different ways but to no success.